# PVLIB: How do I fix value error when reading tmy3 files on tmy.py?

Tags: pvlib

I am writing a program to evaluate the hourly energy output from PV in various cities in the US. For simplicity, I have them in a dictionary (tmy3_cities) so that I can loop through them. To read the code, I followed the [TMY to Power Tutorial off Github](https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tmy_to_power.ipynb). Rather than showing the whole loop, I have only added the code that reads and shifts the time by 30-min.

Accordingly, the code taken from the tutorial works for all of the TMY3 files except for Houston, Atlanta, and Baltimore (HAB, for simplicity). All of the tmy3 files were downloaded from [NREL](https://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/tmy3/by_state_and_city.html) and renamed for my own use. The error I get in reading these three files is related to the datetime, and it essentially comes down to a "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1' after some traceback.

Rather than looping into the same problem, I entered each file into the reader individually, and sure enough, only the HAB tmy3 files give errors.

Secondly, I downloaded the files again. This, obviously had no impact.

In a lazy attempt to bypass the issue, I copied and pasted the date and time columns from working tmy3 files (e.g., Miami) into the non-working ones (i.e., HAB) via excel.

I am not sure what else to do, as I am still fairly new to Python and coding in general.

```
#The dictionary below is not important to the problem below, but is 
provided only for some clarification.
tmy3_cities = {'miami': 'TMY3Miami.csv',
        'houston': 'TMY3Houston.csv',
        'phoenix': 'TMY3Phoenix.csv',
        'atlanta': 'TMY3Atlanta.csv',
        'los_angeles': 'TMY3LosAngeles.csv',
        'las_vegas': 'TMY3LasVegas.csv',
        'san_francisco': 'TMY3SanFrancisco.csv',
        'baltimore': 'TMY3Baltimore.csv',
        'albuquerque': 'TMY3Albuquerque.csv',
        'seattle': 'TMY3Seattle.csv',
        'chicago': 'TMY3Chicago.csv',
        'denver': 'TMY3Denver.csv',
        'minneapolis': 'TMY3Minneapolis.csv',
        'helena': 'TMY3Helena.csv',
        'duluth': 'TMY3Duluth.csv',
        'fairbanks': 'TMY3Fairbanks.csv'}

#The code below was taken from the tutorial.
pvlib_abspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(pvlib)))

#This is the only section of the code that was modified.
datapath = os.path.join(pvlib_abspath, 'data', 'TMY3Atlanta.csv')

tmy_data, meta = pvlib.tmy.readtmy3(datapath, coerce_year=2015)
tmy_data.index.name = 'Time'

# TMY data seems to be given as hourly data with time stamp at the end
# Shift the index 30 Minutes back for calculation of sun positions
tmy_data = tmy_data.shift(freq='-30Min')['2015']

print(tmy_data.head())
```

I would expect each tmy3 file that is read to produce its own tmy_data DataFrame. Please comment if you'd like to see the whole

Comment: Have you tried reading directly from the NREL website? I have no trouble reading Houston (Bush Intercontinental), Atlanta, and Baltimore files directly from the website. e.g. `dataatl, metadataatl = pvlib.iotools.read_tmy3('https://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/722190TYA.CSV', coerce_year=2015)`. Maybe an issue between when you download and when you read.

Comment: Hello Will! Thanks for the quick response. Your suggestion fixed the issue for both Atlanta and Houston; however, I now get a new error for Baltimore: 'ValueError: day is out of range for month'. I am currently searching the website to see if anyone else has run into this error.